# Which Rust structure does this?

Tags: rust

I'm sure there's something out there, but I'm missing the keyword for it :)

I want a `Vec` (or some other similar structure that uses the heap) that can hold only N values, but with the following twist:

If the capacity is full, the next `.push()` will drop the first value. So, the structure will keep being full, but with the latest pushed value at the bottom.

I can DIY it but I'm new to Rust and so I fear that my implementation won't be neither efficient nor elegant.

Thank you!

Comment: There isn't a structure exactly like that in the standard library, but you could write a thin wrapper around VecDeque.

Comment: It sounds like you want a circular buffer/ring buffer, maybe the [circular_queue](https://docs.rs/circular-queue/0.2.6/circular_queue/) or [ringbuffer](https://crates.io/crates/ringbuffer) crates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data structure you are looking for is a circular buffer. You can find many implementations on https://crates.io/, but it's also not difficult to roll your own. Here's a minimal implementation that you could use as a starting point:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct CircularBuffer<T> {
    start: usize,
    data: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T> CircularBuffer<T> {
    pub fn new(capacity: usize) -> Self {
        Self {
            start: 0,
            data: Vec::with_capacity(capacity),
        }
    }

    pub fn push(&mut self, item: T) {
        if self.data.len() < self.data.capacity() {
            self.data.push(item);
        } else {
            self.data[self.start] = item;
            self.start += 1;
            if self.start == self.data.capacity() {
                self.start = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    pub fn get(&self, index: usize) -> Option<&T> {
        if index >= self.data.len() {
            return None;
        }
        let mut index = index + self.start;
        if index > self.data.capacity() {
            index -= self.data.capacity()
        }
        self.data.get(index)
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `push()` could return `Option<T>` with the element it dropped from the circular buffer. Also, `#[derive(Clone)]` would probably be useful and come at no additional cost.

Comment: Sure, this can be expanded in many ways depending on the use case. I actually thought about both these changes, but I didn't want to distract from the essence of the data structure.

Comment: Good point. And my proposal of just adding `Clone` to the list of derives would actually not work because cloning a vector [doesn't copy the capacity](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3ca4b1adbf8bfed4750f74d7055b7bc5).

Answer (score 1):

The standard library's [`VecDeque`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html) is in fact built *on* a circular buffer a.k.a. ring buffer, with the addition of growability. So, you could use `VecDeque` while making sure (possibly via a wrapper type) to delete an item before inserting one if it's full, and you'll get implementations of everything else (like iteration, and rearranging it to be contiguous if desired).

Comment: To enforce the invariant, you would have to use a wrapper type, so you'd still need to write wrappers for all traits impls. These wrappers only need to forward to the underlying impls, so they would be trivial to write, but you'd still need to write them, and think about which trait impls actually conserve the invariant.